# How do I extract text between two commas in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I extract text between two commas in Excel?

```
92 4th Street North, Providence, RI 02904
```

In this case, how would I extract "Providence" substring using simple Excel formulas (`LEN`, `FIND`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula.

```
=MID(A2,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","^",1))+1,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","^",2))-FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","^",1))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,FIND(",",A1)),FIND(",",RIGHT(A1,FIND(",",A1)))-1)
```

Considering your data is on `A1`

Answer (score 0):

@RAJA-THEVAR's formula worked very well for me with a list of over 2500 addresses, as long as the address only contained two commas. With an address like "100 Washington Street, Suite 225, Denver, CO 80220" it returns "Suite 225." I used the following formula to identify and addresses that contained more than two commas:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))
```

Many of these many-comma addresses had strange formats or information, and I found it better to fix them by hand.